# Expo Face Detector Angle

Tags: android, ios, expo, face-detection, expo-camera

I was trying to implement live face detection using Expo-Face detector;
I encountered a mysterious problem in which turning left was not recognizable for ios, but worked properly for android;
There was no documentation about it;
I couldn't figure out how this could happen, cause Documentation and issues had nothing about it;

Now that I found the reason, I'm writing it in case somebody someday encounters this

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that The Angles in android are from 0 to 360, but in ios, they're from -180 to +180!
So, when you turn left, the angle comes about 330 in android, but it comes about -30 in IOS;

So, be careful about it and make min/max Angle based on Platform. :)
GLuck